# updating(PUT) array in express js

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, express

i am using expressjs(nodejs). I am trying to store array data while updating existing data (`dealtype` & `dealprice`), but unable to do so.

my existing dataset

```
{
 "_id": "56a59a2923e047bc2128cd99",
 "foodImageUrl": "modules/foods/client/img/food.jpg",
 "deal": [
  {
   "_id": "56a59a2923e047bc2128cd9a",
   "dealprice": "asd",
   "dealtype": "asd"
  }
 ],
 "name": "ads",
 "created": "2016-01-25T03:44:41.346Z"
}
```

my expressjs controller

```
exports.update = function (req, res) {
var food = req.food;

  food.name = req.body.name;
  food.deal.dealtype = req.body.deal.dealtype;
  food.deal.dealprice = req.body.deal.dealprice;
  food.foodImageUrl = req.body.foodImageUrl;

  food.save(function (err) {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(400).send({
        message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
      });
    } else {
      res.json(food);
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: Is `mongoose` used in your code?

Comment: yes mongoose is used

Comment: Only update the dealtype & dealprice on the existing document? or create one new document?

Comment: i would like to update on the existing document

Answer (score 0):

One way to update the existing document. First of all, find the document need to changed by `_id` or other key word. here is one sample by `_id`.

```
Food.findOne({_id: req.food._id}, function(err, food) {
  food.name = req.body.name;
  food.deal.dealtype = req.body.deal.dealtype;
  food.deal.dealprice = req.body.deal.dealprice;
  food.foodImageUrl = req.body.foodImageUrl;

  food.save(function (err) {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(400).send({
        message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
      });
    } else {
      res.json(food);
    }
  });
});
```

Or just use the [`findOneAndUpdate`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate) to update the existing document.

Comment: it says `Error: [$resource:badcfg] Error in resource configuration for action `update`. Expected response to contain an array but got an object` in the console

Comment: i am using angularjs in the frontend `food.deal.dealtype = req.body.deal.dealtype;` does this fetch ng-repeat data?